# Pull specific data from a webpage based on a list of elements

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a tool in Excel that will pull data from Amazon and more specifically the Kindle (ebooks) section. Amazon uses IDs for their ebooks that can be seen in their URLs. For instance, B0192CTMYG is "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone" as you can see here: http://www.amazon.com/dp/product/B0192CTMYG.

What I would like to do, is be able to paste a list of these IDs and for this tool to retrieve 2 pieces of information: 
1. The price. (if any)
2. If it can be read for free as a part of Kindle Unlimited or not.

Ideally, this tool would not only check on amazon.com but also amazon.co.uk, amazon.fr, amazon.de etc...

I'm not really sure how to get started on this or if Excel is actually the best tool but it's the one I'm most comfortable with. That being said, I'm open to suggestions.

Thank you!

EDIT1 22/01/2016

Here's the code I currently have that works for me. For a start, I opted for a cell modification as a trigger for the code. This requires you to: 
1. go to "Visual Basic" and, in the two drop-down menus, select "Worksheet" and "Change" respectfully. 
2. "Define" cell B1 as ASIN and B2 as "In_KU?"

The expected result is to type an ID in B1 and B2 will return the HTML inner text.

Here's the code so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Row = Application.Workbooks("workbookname").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("ID").Row And _
Target.Column = Application.Workbooks("workbookname").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("ID").Column Then

Dim IE As New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate "http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/" & Application.Workbooks("workbookname").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("ID").Value

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set doc = IE.document
Dim BB As String
BB = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("span")(220).innerText)

Application.Workbooks("workbookname").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("In_KU?").Value = BB
IE.Quit
MsgBox ("Finished")

End If

End Sub
```

`("span")(220)` isn't returning the value I need which is "Read for Free". There's about 13k lines of HTML in every detail page on Amazon and I'm not sure how to be extra specific.

EDIT2 08/02/2016

Here's the code that works with a single value. I've renamed the ID (ASIN):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Row = Application.Workbooks("bretttest - Copy").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("ASIN").Row And _
Target.Column = Application.Workbooks("bretttest - Copy").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("ASIN").Column Then

Dim IE As New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate "http://www.amazon" & Application.Workbooks("bretttest - Copy").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B1").Value & "/dp/" & Application.Workbooks("bretttest - Copy").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("ASIN").Value

Do
DoEvents

Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set doc = IE.document
Dim BB As String

BB = Trim(doc.getElementById("kuBadge"))

Application.Workbooks("bretttest - Copy").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("In_KU?").Value = BB

IE.Quit
MsgBox ("Finished")

End If

End Sub
```

So when an ASIN is added to cell A3 it returns "[object HTMLImageElement]" when the Kindle Unlimited badge is there. Now what I would really need is for this to work not only for a single cell but rather a range of cells. So if I paste 50 ASINs in A3:A53, it returns "[object HTMLImageElement]" for all of those that have it and nothing if it doesn't. I guess I'll probably need an "On Error" statement somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This VBA sub will go through a webpage looking for links. You would need to view the code behind the page you're looking at to modify it accordingly, but it is a start. You will need to add references to "Microsoft HTML Object Library" and "Microsoft XML, v6.0" (or a different version depending on your version of Excel) via "Tools / References":

```
Public Sub parsePage()
  Dim ie As Variant
  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  ie.Visible = False

  Dim DOC As HTMLDocument
  Dim idx As Integer
  Dim data As String

  Dim links As Variant
  Dim lnk As Variant

  ie.navigate enter the url here
  Do
    DoEvents
  Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4
  Set DOC = ie.Document

  Set links = DOC.getElementsByTagName("li")
  cnt = 0
  For Each lnk In links
    data = lnk.innerText
  Next
Wend
Set ie = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: I assume you know how to create a VBA macro in Excel. If not, let us know.

Comment: Why `Microsoft XML, v6.0` for an `InternetExplorer.Application` based scrape?

Comment: It might not be needed. I worked off different examples and it might be an extraneous ref...

Comment: Hello! Thank you for this! However, I'm unclear on how to do this part: "You will need to add references to "Microsoft HTML Object Library" and "Microsoft XML, v6.0" (or a different version depending on your version of Excel) via "Tools / References":". Also, I'm a bit unsure where to add the code of the page source in here. Do you think you could show me what it looks like using the Harry Potter book from the initial message? (Sorry, I'm fairly new to all this and thanks a ton for your help so far!

Comment: To add references, go to your VBA for Applications window. Click "Tools" on the ribbon and then click on "References". You should only need the "Microsoft HTML Object Library".

Comment: On the line "ie.navigate" replace "enter the url here" with the URL you are searching for (http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0192CTMYG/?tag=stackoverfl08-20 in your example).

Comment: The "Set links" line will have to change, you'll want to replace "li" with a tag to search by. You'll have to go to the page you're looking at, and click "Page" and then "View source". You'll then have to search through the page to find out what element(s) to search by. This will be the tricky part. Looking at the source, it looks like Amazon is using a lot of images and lookups to fill the page.

Comment: Excellent! That's a lot for me to go on. I'll take a good stab at this in the morning and come back. Thanks so much for your patience.

Comment: So, I went to the Amazon website and right-clicked the "Read for Free" button and then clicked on "Inspect element" to see what the code was. It appeas to be this: 
`<a class="a-button-text a-text-center" id="a-autoid-0-announce" role="button" href="/gp/kindle/ku/sign-up/ui/ref=ku_lp_rw_dp_bb">
                    Read for Free
                </a>`
What is my "Tag Name" in there? (to replace "li" in the macro)

Comment: I actually just tried to replace "li" with "input" and tried to run it but got a "wend without while" error. I then put wend in comment to see how it ran without it and got "automation error the object invoked has disconnected from its clients". It highlights the following piece of code:
`Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4`

Comment: Solved by replacing `Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` with `Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium`. Nothing appears in the sheet though, is that normal?

Comment: When I created that code, there was a lot of trial and error to find what I needed. If it found nothing, the code probably needs to be modified to search for something else. From your inspection of "Read for Free", the tag name is "a", which defines the hyperlink. You might have to go through all "a" tags until you find "Read for free" in the innertext and then set up a different loop to look at a different tag for your other values.

Comment: Also, if you could modify your original question to show the code you currently have...

Comment: Done! Any suggestions on how I can go through all the "a" tags in a single operation? Thanks again, PKatona!

Comment: Change Set links to this: 'Set links = DOC.getElementsByTagName("a")'.  In the For loop, you'll have to look at the data for the specific string "Read for free", and you can try any other values you're looking for. But as I said before the other values you're looking for may be under a different tag, so you might end up having a few different loops with "Set links" commands.

Comment: I didn't scroll up enough. You'll want to incorporate something similar to the "Set links" in my example per the previous comment, and you'll have to loop - there will be multiple values with that tag name and you can't assume it will always be the same number.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of replies, I've been pulled in other projects before I could finish this one. I modified the "BB" to this: 
`BB = Trim(doc.getElementById("kuBadge"))`
Because I noticed the other KindleUnlimited button on the page had this source: <img id="kuBadge" src="http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/kindle/ku/pDP-KU-badge_prime-height._CB344727476_.png">
It now returns "[object HTMLImageElement]" when I enter an ID (which is good progress). I just have to turn that into something more obvious for the user. What would be great is if I could get the src img to popup instead

Comment: I'll look into the Amazon site tonight. Make sure you have the question updated to show the code as it exists now. I'll see if I can figure out a what to search for.

Comment: Updated! reiterating the last part of my update: when an ASIN is added to cell A3 it returns "[object HTMLImageElement]" when the Kindle Unlimited badge is there. Now what I would really need is for this to work not only for a single cell but rather a range of cells. So if I paste 50 ASINs in A3:A53, it returns "[object HTMLImageElement]" for all of those that have it and nothing if it doesn't. I guess I'll probably need an "On Error" statement somewhere.

Comment: Hi PKatona! Quick update, a friend of mine tells me working with ranges in a "cell-change" environment. Is this correct? He says it's far easier to use a manual trigger (button) and a loop for this purpose.